# Why do 'Unexpected value NaN parsing y attribute.' warning is displayed while drawing pie chart using ExtJS?

Tags: extjs4, pie-chart

I am trying to draw an pie chart using ExtJS but something is going wrong. I can see following warnings in firebug window :

```
Unexpected value NaN parsing y attribute.
Unexpected value NaN parsing height attribute.
```

Code for my pie chart is as follows :

```
xtype: 'chart',
title: 'Location wise candidate distribution',
itemId: 'CandidateDistributionChart',
store: 'CandidateDistribution',
width: 250,
height: 260,
shadow: true,
animate: true,
theme: 'Base:gradients',
legend: {
    position: 'right'
},
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    field: 'candidateCount',
    showInLegend: true,
    label: {
        field: 'name',
        contrast: true,
        font: '18px Arial'
    }
}]
```

Why do those warnings are coming? Currently chart is not getting drawn even though I have mentioned all the necessary values.

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a string to define the store, but it needs a store object.
2 solutions :

1) `store: Ext.getCmp('CandidateDistribution'),`

Or 2) Define the store into a variable this way `chartStore =  Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { ... });` and then pass it to the chart config : `store: chartStore`

But maybe it's not the problem according to the errors... Can you post the code of your store, your model, and the container of your chart ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the value at least one value is not null or not zero. If all zeros or null you will have this type of error.

this is the model. I added the return and it worked. is a quick fix

```
{name: 'HD', type: 'number', convert: function(value,record){
 if (value == 0)
     return 0.0001 // The graphic needs at least one of the values to be more than 0 or will throw an error.
  else     
     return value;
  }
},
```